# Rich Text field from Visual Studio

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013. I am using SharePoint online 2013. I am creating a "SharePoint-hosted" App. I have added a List to the project called "Technology". I added a field called "Technology Description". I gave it a type of "Multiple Lines of Text". I published the solution and went to `https://spurl/debugsite/SPApp/Lists/Technology/` and then clicked on "New Item" but I do not get the Rich Text Toolbar that I would like to have there.

Back in Visual Studio I do not see any place for me to make this Multiple Lines of Text rich text. I tried to edit the `"Schema.xml"` file associated with this list and to the `Field` element with the `Name` attributes of `Technology Description` I added the following attributes: `RichText="true" RichTextMode="FullHtml"` but that doesn't seem to have helped.

I also want to allow the list columns to be modified by the user after deployment of this solution; however, the "List Settings" button does not appear when managing the list.

Therefore the questions that I have are:

1. How can I get this "Technology Description" field to show the Rich Text toolbar when the field is being edited in the standard / default New Item / Edit Item actions
2. How can I make it such that when the solution is deployed the user is able to go in to the List Settings for the list and add columns if they so choose after the solution has been deployed to their SharePoint site?

In a nutshell I want to be able to make it so that the Lists which I add to the Solution in Visual Studio will behave more like Custom Lists generated from the "Site Contents" -> "Add an App" -> "Custom List".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following
In case if its a visual web part

```
    <SharePoint:EmbeddedFormField ID="sp_summary"  FieldName="WikiField" ControlMode="New" DisableInputFieldLabel="false" runat="server" >
```

In Sharepoint list settings-->Select your column --> Select
  Enhanced rich text (Rich text with pictures, tables, and hyperlinks)

Comment: Avinash, thank you for your reply; however, in my question I stated that after the solution had been deployed and I go to `https://spurl/debugsite/SPApp/Lists/Technology` the "List Settings" icon does not appear. So that is one part of what I am trying to accomplish is enable that.

Comment: its not a visual web part solution right?

Comment: That is correct this was made using "Templates" -> "Visual Basic" -> "Office/SharePoint" -> "App for SharePoint 2013".

Comment: Sorry my solution works for Templates-->Visual c#

Comment: Understood. I did a C# one and ran in to the same problems; however, I have figured out half of the solution. basically in the "Schema.xml" file I needed to add `IsolateStyles="TRUE"` and `NumLines="15"` to the `Field` element and now I at least have my Rich Text editor that I was expecting. The "List Settings" button for this list is still missing though.

Comment: Do u have enough permissions to edit the list?, did u check if ur in site collection administrators group?

Comment: Yep I am apart of the site collection administrators group and also the site owners group within the site as well. I am just going to chalk that potion up to just being a difference between SharePoint online and SharePoint On-Premise. Thanks for your help anyway. I will be satisfied with the `RichText="TRUE" RichTextMode="FullHtml" IsolateStyles="TRUE" NumLines="15"` in my field element for now and maybe deal with why this lists are not customizable after deployment later.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the following attributes to the field after Type="Note" in the schema:

   `RichText="TRUE" RichTextMode="FullHtml"`
2. Provide a link somewhere in your app to your List Settings page:

   `appweburl + "/_layouts/15/listedit.aspx?List=" + ListID;`

Hope this helps
Alan